# WebDriver is not able to find out WebElement where as same css works fine when I use Selenium IDE

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am using Firefox WebDriver, and in my test it is not able to find out Link/Image WebElement for some reason.

When I use Selenium IDE with same CSS (which is not working with WebDriver), it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone please suggest on what changes I have to do in xpath, of CSS Selector while using WebDriver? I don't know what I am missing here.

**My HTML page Code look like below:** I want to click on "New" link/image.

```
<div id="toolbarcontainer">
<ul id="toolbarlist">
    <li>
        <a id="btnNewDashboard" title="New" onclick="javascript:$('#dialogAddTab').dialog('open'); return false;" href="#">
            <span class="toolbarlistimg"></span>
            <span class="toolbarlisttext"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul> </div>
```

**With Selenium IDE Record and play works fine with below code:**

`<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.toolbarlisttext</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>`

**But when I use below code in my test, it didn't work... I tried following - Please suggest**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.toolbarlisttext")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("toolbarlisttext")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[@class='toolbarlisttext']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("css=span.toolbarlisttext")).click();
```

Thanks,

**Updates: 2 Jan 2015**

New button/link is actually under iFrame, and I was totally ignoring iFrame. After that I could able to click on New link. Answer is mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friend realized that "New" link/img is in iFrame, and as it is in iFrame we have to first switch focus to iFrame and then Click on Element.

**Sample code:**

```
// Switch the focus to iFrame first
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Framework_Client_BusinessIntelligence_0']/iframe")));
// Click on Link/Button/Image present in iFrame
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnNewDashboard']")).click();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to target `a` tag here:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnNewDashboard")).click();
```

or, using `By.cssSelector`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#btnNewDashboard")).click();
```

Comment: I tried that also.. but didn't mention it in above post.. this also didn't work :(. Thanks!

Comment: @PareshkumarChaudhari okay, what are the symptoms? are you getting any errors?

Comment: All the time I am getting same error... WebElement with so and so method, and Element Name not present or not found.

Comment: @PareshkumarChaudhari may be there is something else going on here. For example, element is not yet present, or the page is not completely loaded. Could you show the current code you have? Thanks.

Comment: I actually found the solution. New button is actually under iFrame. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#toolbarlist > #btnNewDashboard > .toolbarlisttext")).click();
```